# Artisan Call not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a multi-tenant app with different tenants having different tables. When I run my code on routes file, it works but when I run in a class the migration fails. Any ideas why?

The code:

> $id = $tenant->id;
>   $con = Config::get('database.default');
>   Config::set('database.connections.'.$con.'.prefix','clinic_'.$id.'_');
>   Artisan::call('migrate', array('--path' => 'app/database/migrations/unit'));

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why aren't you calling artisan from the command line? And what is the error?

Comment: I want to call it at runtime. When someone creates a new tenant. The unfortunate part is it doesn't show any error :( that just makes debugging hard. All I know is it doesn't use the recently updated config.